# passing the filename to a python script in command line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, cmd

I want to pass the name of a file to a python script while I'm running it from the command line. I'm trying this clear command:

```
cat enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml | python WikiExtractor.py -b 500K -o extracted
```

however, it gives an error:

```
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're running the command in Windows. In windows, there's no `cat` installed unless you installed.

You can use [`type`](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command instead:

```
type enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml | python WikiExtractor.py -b 500K -o extracted
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be **python WikiExtractor.py -b5 -o extracted -f enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml**.

And use **sys.argv** array of input arguments of python command from **sys** command.
This may help:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: I think we should declare the filename before the script name. However, thanks for the suggestion of sys.argv. That's also another possible approach.